# VS Code ESLint — resolve plugins from custom directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

How can I get ESLint setup with VS Code when my `node_modules` is not in the workspace root?

```
root/
  third_party/
     node_modules/
  .eslintrc
  src/
    (source files)
```

In the VS Code settings, I have ESLint setup to load from the custom node_modules location:

```
"eslint.nodePath": "third_party/node_modules"
```

However, I'm still getting the following error message:

```
Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc': Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'
Require stack:
- /path/to/repo/__placeholder__.js
Referenced from: /path/to/repo/.eslintrc
Happened while validating /path/to/repo/src/index.ts
This can happen for a couple of reasons:
1. The plugin name is spelled incorrectly in an ESLint configuration file (e.g. .eslintrc).
2. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin' is installed globally as well.
3. If ESLint is installed locally, then '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin' isn't installed correctly.
```

And here's my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
    "plugins": [],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "ignorePatterns": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I saw there's a CLI option (`--resolve-plugins-relative-to`) that will tell ESLint where to look for the plugins, but that doesn't seem to be exposed to the `.eslintrc` or in the VS Code extension settings.

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--resolve-plugins-relative-to

Due to my specific circumstance, changing the directory structure is not possible.

Comment: You know, using the VS Code extension, and the CLI can give very different error messages. One can even work while the other doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps you want to take a look on this article: [eslint.nodePath only works with absolute paths in multi module vscode workspaces](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1225).

Comment: @jD3V, next time, please don't edit the question to become something materially different. The core issue here is about getting ESLint to work in VS Code, not working from the CLI. I already have it working from the CLI. I've rolled it back to the original question.

Comment: Your having an issue differentiating the extension from ESLint. The eslint extension operates the ESLint cli for you through VS Code commands. VSCode has absolutely nothing to do with the error message you are getting.

Comment: The only way that you are able to configure ESLint to work, when you node_modules directory isn't in your root (as of right now, because of what I mentioned below, ESLint doesn't support adding an eslint configuration to your `~/` directory). You think that the eslint extension for VS Code cause the errors but any error logged in your terminal is from VSCode, and any error the extension gives is from eslint through a problem matcher. The extension is nothing but an abstraction layer connecting eslint to vscode commands and syntax-errors through a vscode problem matcher.

Comment: And I didn't change the question, I changed the part where you used the word setup, and a couple other instances that similarly used improper semantics/English. You are not "setting up"  ESLint, you are "installing and configuring" ESLint. No one ever got very far configuring a project with ther setup file, and no one ever got very far using `npm setup eslint`

Comment: @nick, I know that this isn't an appropriate solution, but in order to narrow it down: Does it work if you use an absolute path like observed in the link I have posted above?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever resolve this?  I'm trying to use `resolve-plugins-relative-to` but it's not working.